# Youtube iframe API not firing events inside custo web component

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, web-component

I have a small solution for digital signage, one of the requirements is to implement a youtube video. I have this done for a single video - so far so good. I want to be able to contain multiple videos on my slides, I want to do this using Web Components, since i then can isolate the JS variables (right?).

When im running within the context of a full page, everything is working as intended. I copied the code into a small web component, but now my events are not being invoked.

That was my first problem. My second problem is that how on earth do i signal my webComponent to start playing (assume there are multiple on the same page).

Markup for the page:

```
  <div class="slide" data-slidetype="youtube">
    <app-medianyoutube></app-medianyoutube>
  </div>
```

JS Code for the webComponent (the function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady is never called).

```html
//usage: <app-medianyoutube video=''></app-medianyoutube>
class MedianYoutube extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("constructor youtubeslide");
    //var videoId = this.getAttribute("video");
    //creates the player div to show the video
    var maindiv = document.createElement("div");
    maindiv.id = "player";

    var tag = document.createElement("script");
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    this.appendChild(maindiv);
    this.appendChild(tag);

    //this is the player and the function that is being called when the API is ready
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      console.log("on youtubeiframe api ready");
      player = new YT.Player("player", {
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        videoId: "aQAEkgxNaQs",
        events: {
          onReady: onPlayerReady,
          onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
        }
      });
    }

    //handles when the player sends a message that it is ready for playback
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
      console.log("onPlayerReady");
      event.target.playVideo();
    }

    //handles when the player sends a message that it is changing state
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
      console.log("onPlayerStateChange: " + event);
      if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        player.seekTo(0);
        player.stopVideo();
        showNextSlide();
        done = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
//register the component
customElements.define("app-medianyoutube", MedianYoutube);
```

Comment: Could it be that the youtube iframe API is an external JS library that cannot be downloaded and added to a web component?

Comment: Brian, for start playing the video, you have to add the `playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1 }` 
- just before the `events` - in the settings of the iframe. You can guide yourself by looking this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSOes/7zndco8r/1/).